# Does charge always reside at the edge of a conductor's surface

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, conductors, coulombs-law

Say I have a circular metal sheet with a charge $Q$ on it do the field lines come out from the edges alone or from across the entire sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The charges repel so they "want to" get as far from each other as possible. So they won't stay in the middle of the sheet but will distribute.

A stable configuration is such that minimizes electric potential energy, which is proportional to average of the quantity $1/distance$ between two charged particles, over all pairs. So this average has to be as small as possible.

If all the particles went to the edges, this quantity would be bigger than if some of them stayed in the middle or anywhere not on the edges.

So to minimize electric potential energy, charge will be everywhere on the surface, with charge density the greatest on the edges, and continuously getting weaker as moving towards the sheet center.

Comment: Energy of a pair of charges with distance $r$ is proportional to $1/r$.

Comment: What do you mean by "distance of curvature"?

Comment: Sorry some stupid thing my teacher said.he is kinda dumb